# Disable taps on edges of the touchpad on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, touchpad

I'm trying to find a solution for palm rejection on Ubuntu. I'm sure I've done that on my previous laptop but I can't find that solution now.

I need to set my touchpad so that it does not register taps on the edges but if a tap was registered in the middle of the trackpad I need to be able to continue the drag up to the physical edge. I was looking for an option in `synclient` but the only option I could find is `AreaLeftEdge` which ignores all movements and in fact simply reduces the area of the touchpad. I also tried to find that option in `xinput` configuration.

How can I set my touchpad so that it ignores taps on the edges but still tracks the drags that have been started in the middle?

Comment: I find it easiest to disable taps altogether, which is simply a Control Centre mouse setting. This doesn't affect edge-scrolling, which works fine.

Comment: I believe this mode of palm rejection is always active when using the _libinput_ driver.